# Passing and returning 2 arrays from a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I have 2 arrays in main function, one double and one integer types. I want to write a function, lets call it "func1" and I want to send 2 arrays to it. I'm going to do some operations (I can give the details of the operations if necessary) on the other two types, and then return that two functions to the my main function.

I understand that it is not possible to return two objects once, so I think I must pass and return pointers.

What I have tried is:

```
int main (void){
...
int str2[]=...
double str3[]=...
func1 (&str2, &str3) /* Thş was the best suggestion I could find on the internet */
...
}

void func1 (int *intType, double *doubleType){
...
intType[33]=27; /* just for example */
...
return;
}
```

as a result, I got dozens of warnings and my program crashes if I run it. What are my problems upthere, and how can I fix them?

P.S. I really do not know what I'm doing wrong and I'm not a master of C, it seems I have serious problems about passing pointers so don't get angry with me please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not far off:

```
void func1 (int *intType, double *doubleType); // note: prototype

int main (void)
{
    int str2[100];
    double str3[100];
    func1 (str2, str3); // note: no `&` on the parameters here
    return 0;
}

void func1 (int *intType, double *doubleType)
{
    intType[33] = 27;
    doubleType[42] = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: well, it just solved my problems. I was expecting something more complicated :) Thanks!

Comment: Note that you should always compile with warnings enabled - this will allow the compiler to point out various kinds of basic mistake.

Comment: Yeah, they are always enabled, but I'm just not experienced enough to understand and solve all kinds of warnings, just like this one :)

Comment: @PaulR: Users should not need to enable warnings in the compiler. They should be on by default, and the compiler should refuse to disable them unless presented with a digital certificate signed by an accredited educational institution indicating that the bearer has shown proficiency in the language.

Comment: There must be some way for `func` to know the length of the arrays, such as a `#define`.

Comment: @user3108849 Program in assembly for something more complicated. :-D

Answer (score 2):

```
int main (void){
...
int str2[]=...
double str3[]=...
func1 (str2, str3) /* Thş was the best suggestion I could find on the internet */
...
}

void func1 (int intType[], double doubleType[]){
...
intType[33]=27; /* just for example */
...
return;
}
```

Comment: if it works,+1 and/or mark it as answer and add anything else you discovered about your problem in comments, for future viewers.

Comment: well I dont have enough reputation yet to +1, and waiting for the time limit to pick one of those, thanks for warning :)